# An uninstaller will only work with a reboot. Can I override this so that I don't have to reboot?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, spyware, adware

I've inadvertently installed some crap on my computer: "YouatubeAdBlocke" [sic] and "NextCoup".

When I try to uninstall them, I'm presented with possibly the most annoying possible message saying:

> This will completely remove the browser add-on. In order for the
>   uninstall to be completed your computer must restart, please click
>   "Yes" in order to complete the uninstall process and **install an**
>   **alternate browser extension** which will save you money while you shop
>   online. Click "NO " to only uninstall and restart your computer. Click
>   " Cancel" to  abort the uninstall process.

*(Bolded for emphasis).*

Now I realise that both of these piece of garbage installations are purely adware/spyware designed to make my life, and the life of others who've also been somehow trapped into installing these, miserable.

I have a tonne of work to do on my machine and having these installed is ridiculous, but I don't want to have to restart the machine to remove them unless I absolutely, unavoidably have to.

Any ideas? Command line processes to remove these without reboot?

I should add, neither of these have product ID/MSI information, so I can't do the typical commandline software removal trick.

Comment: You can probably cripple them without rebooting, but it would take some knowledge of the specific programs, I suspect.

Comment: [Remove YoutubeAdBlocker adware (Virus Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/youtubeadblocker-virus-removal/), [How to remove NextCoup Ads (Virus Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/nextcoup-virus-removal/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with "Cancel" for now and later do "No." Most well behaved software will tell you at the end that a reboot is needed and give you the option of "reboot later."  I have a feeling that you are not dealing with well behaved software and that it will cause the machine to reboot if you click "No" without giving you the option to do it later.

I agree that part about "install an alternate browser extension" was pretty sleazy. It's good you caught it.

Comment: Admittedly, I didn't catch it at first. I lazily clicked "yes" when I removed another adware program, and my computer rebooted without me being aware that it would (assuming that it was just asking if I in fact wanted it removed). It was only when I noticed that in removing this software that it looked conspicuously the same, and that the date of installation was the same as the date of removal of the last, that I bothered to read it.